# Unable to git clone

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I want to clone repository by using following command.

```
 git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
```

I have got following error with this command.

```
dev@ubuntu:/a/WebRtc/Tools$ 
dev@ubuntu:/a/WebRtc/Tools$git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
Cloning into 'depot_tools'...
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
dev@ubuntu:/a/WebRtc/Tools$
```

[image: this is the link of the screenshot]

I have tried this in following ways:

- Update git version.
- Try with Ubuntu 15.10 and 14.04.4.
- Try same command in windows machine, it working.

Comment: Try to clone without a sudo

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried it, but still not working.

Comment: Can you browse https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git in we browser (lynx / links) on this machine?

Comment: Have you tried without the .git at the end? `git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools`

Answer (score 0):

Such an error message during a *clone* (not a push or pull) indicates that git is not able to properly create the local repo.
See for instance "[Cannot git clone to VMWare shared folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35531205/6309)", where the impossibility to create hard-link was problematic.

Check:

- if your user has the right to create file/symlink/hardlink, or
- if there is some kind [apparmor policy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor) which would prevent/limit the creation of files in your setup, or
- if `/a/WebRTC` is a mounted folder with restricted rights