# Git clone into VMWare shared folder not working

Tags: git, git-clone, shared-directory, vmware-fusion

I'm running a Ubuntu 14.04 VM in VMWare Fusion (host machine El Capitan OS x). I've set up shared folders between the host and VM. In a shared folder if I try to `git clone` any remote repo, git seems to ignore the remote repo, and exits with an error:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git clone git@github.com:example/example.git
trace: built-in: git 'clone' 'git@github.com:example/example.git'
Cloning into 'example'...
trace: run_command: 'git-upload-pack '\''origin'\'''
trace: exec: '/bin/sh' '-c' 'git-upload-pack '\''origin'\''' 'git-upload-pack '\''origin'\'''
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Running the same command in a non-shared folder on the VM works correctly:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git clone git@github.com:example/example.git
trace: built-in: git 'clone' 'git@github.com:example/example.git'
Cloning into 'example'...
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@github.com' 'git-upload-pack '\''example/example.git'\'''
trace: run_command: 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 6567 on dev' '--check-self-contained-and-connected'
trace: exec: 'git' 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 6567 on dev' '--check-self-contained-and-connected'
remote: Counting objects: 1, done.
trace: built-in: git 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 6567 on dev' '--check-self-contained-and-connected'
Receiving objects:  100%
[command runs normally from here...]
```

There's a clear difference in the `git-upload-pack` execution. For some reason it's not running SSH (I've also tried HTTPS, again the remote repo is ignored). What I can't work out is why this is happening and how to make `git clone` work in the shared folder.

I've checked filesystem permissions and they are fine. I can't see why these would affect the behaviour of `git clone` at this early stage (and in this way...).

My problem may be the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393077/cannot-git-clone-to-vmware-shared-folder), but there was no answer provided. The `GIT_TRACE` I have run might provide more information and not using SSH seems very strange.

I have managed to set up my repo on the shared filesystem without using git clone (by cloning somewhere else, then re-using the `.git/config` file), but I need to be able to `git clone` directly in the folder as it's also affecting submodules & I have a lot of repos! Can anyone help?

Comment: Try with sudo/root privillages

Comment: VMware shared folders are broken. Try to avoid using them.

Comment: @andrew-medico: I know shared folders aren't perfect, but (apart from being interested such a weird problem), what would be a decent alternative?

Comment: sudo doesn't help, it's not a privilege problem from what I can see.

Comment: @Steve Did you ever resolve your issue using VMWare Fusion and shared folders?

Comment: @jbobbins: Unfortunately not. I use sshfs instead.